# How to convert NSString* to ANTLR3_UINT8 or ANTLR3_UINT16

Tags: c, objective-c, antlr

Could somebody tell me what is the proper way to convert a NSString* to an ANTLR3 string (used in C) ?

EDIT: this seems to work

```
   char buf[255];   
   if ( YES == [myNSString getCString:buf maxLength:255 encoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy] )
   {
      pANTLR3_UINT8 theExpression = (pANTLR3_UINT8*)buf;
      ...
```

Comment: What that's doing is forcing a conversion to ASCII. The `encoding:` parameter expects a string encoding value (specifying what character set to use), but what you're passing it (NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy) is an "encoding conversion option". The value of "NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy" is 1, which is equal to "NSASCIIStringEncoding", which is "Strict 7-bit ASCII encoding within 8-bit chars; ASCII values 0…127 only."

Comment: thanks, yes I know I am doing a conversion however so far I haven't found any better way, is there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you want the complete string without loss, you can use the following code:

```
NSString *myString = ...;
NSUInteger len = [myString lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
char *buf = malloc(len + 1);
if ([myString getCString:buf maxLength:(len + 1) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]) {
    // pANTLR3_UINT8 is equivalent to ANTLR3_UINT8*
    pANTLR3_UINT8 theExpression = (pANTLR3_UINT8) buf;
}
free(buf);
```

Of course you can use another encoding if character loss is not important.

Comment: after some experimenting I got about the same, thank you nevertheless.